# Idea of paying for things with time

Tags: history-of, time, jean-le-flambeur, quantum-thief

I recently read the [Quantum Thief](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0765329492).

This book had the idea of the time you live as something that can be used to pay for things. When you run out of "money" you die.

I was wondering is this the original source for this idea? Or does anyone know of an earlier book with the same idea?

Comment: There's the *Lost in Space* Episode [The Time Merchant](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0636250/), but that was 1968 which is a little after the accepted answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The earliest I know of is ["Repent, Harlequin!" Said the Ticktockman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Repent,_Harlequin!%22_Said_the_Ticktockman) by Harlan Ellison (Written in 1965).  Attorneys representing the author are actually suing the creators of the movie "In Time" because of its similarities to the short story.

Answer (score 6):

Not the same thing, I guess, but here is the editorial blurb for [Wallace West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace_West)'s story ["The Time-Lockers"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?90328) in [*Science Fiction Quarterly*, August **1956**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?60375+c) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Science_Fiction_Quarterly_New_Series_v04n04_1956-08#page/n5/mode/2up)):

> You've heard about time-saving devices, but suppose there were some sort of dingus through which you could actually save up time, like money. Well, that's how it was here; people snipped off time ordinarily spent in commuting, etc., until they had a month or so on deposit, then went off for a vacation on a parallel world where the time-rates were different. Their month was only equal to a day or so, here, you see. But what was the meaning of the dreams they had at night in vacation-land?

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite an answer, but [Momo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momo_%28novel%29), by Michael Ende, has the concept of Time being something that can be stolen by thieves.

Comment: As we're searching for the earliest, let's add a date.  Published in 1973 I think.

Answer (score 4):

"*La Carte"* by Marcel Aymé (1942) translated as "*The Ration Ticket*", is told as the diary of character Jules Flegmon.

A [translated version](https://stresscafe.com/translations/ayme/aymehome.html) can be read for free online.

In the society:

> In order to ward off shortages and insure a greater output from the
> laboring element of the population, there will supposedly be
> executions of non-productive consumers: the elderly, the retired,
> those of independent means, the unemployed and other non-essential
> persons.

Jules then finds out that individuals will not be put to death but will instead have their time alive each month reduced.

> Naturally, putting all the non-essential to death is out of the
> question. The plan will simply cut back on their time alive. Maleffroi
> explained to me that they will be entitled to so many days of
> existence per month according to their degree of uselessness.

When an individual's time runs out they simply disappear. On the 1st of the following month they reappear with no memory of the gap as well as no clothes at the location they disappeared.

The individuals who have their time cut start to buy extra days on the black market and find that they can actually live more days in a month than exist. The black market price start at around 200 franc's but increases to several thousand.

Individuals buy so much time that they live for several years in a month.

> There is the story, among others, of the extraordinarily wealthy M.
> Wadé, who is supposed to have lived between June 30 and July 1 a total
> of one thousand nine hundred sixty-seven days, that is, a mere five
> years and four months.

Individuals who do not live the extra time do not remember what happened in it when they are asked by individual's who did.

At the end of the story the ration tickets are abolished.

Comment: It looks like time is more of a good you can purchase, than something you can use to make purchases, but still interesting all the same.

Comment: There is a black market where the poor are selling their time to give their dependents more opportunities, it's only 2/3 lines in the overall story though.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that time is money (namely, a resource with inherent worth), is a very old one.

The first mention I found by a historic figure was [Benjamin Franklin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Is_Money), though I'm fairly certain that the philosophical idea, if not the precise wording, pre-dates him.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing a short film on television where infants were implanted with a crystal or gadget that interacted with a handheld device to facilitate commerce using one's remaining lifespan as currency. The main character is an enterprising youth who accumulates a sizable retirement and then gives it away to his parent or mentor before wandering out into the world.

It aired around 1990, I think. And it was paired with another short about two kids who put insects on golfballs and launched them into the heavens to escape the mundane existence of the trailerpark.

Answer (score 0):

Camus discusses this topic in **[A Happy Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Happy_Death)**, which was composed between 1936 and 1938, although it wasn't published until 1971.  In it, the character Zagreus states:

> "Only it takes time to be happy. A lot of time. Happiness, too, is a long patience. And in almost every case, we use up our lives making money, when we should be using our money to gain time."

A full English translation of the book can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4apn4pIdw2HLTA3R2tCTHRkX0E/edit).

Comment: This is an answer, but would be better as a comment, as answers need some evidence, just like Myth.SE.